# Hide Console Window during Process.Start

Tags: c#, process, console

How can I get rid of the console window? I have the ProcessStartInfo as below

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
       FileName = "cmd.exe",
       WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
       UseShellExecute = false,
       CreateNoWindow = true,
       RedirectStandardInput = true,
    };
    Process.Start(processStartInfo).StandardInput.WriteLine(argHandlerArgs);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the console?  Are you just trying to quietly execute a command script in the background without it showing to the main user?

Comment: When I run the code with `WriteLine("exit")` I don't see a console window open...